# How do you perform arithmetic on values produced by Scanner in java?

Tags: java

I really would like to know how to add, multiply or divide using a scanner class because every time I run the code it always gives me 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int NumPerHamper;
double ItemCost;
int NumHampersMade;
int NumItemsLeftOver;
int ValuePerHamper;
    int NumAvalable;
double ValueAllotedHampers;
double NumAllotedPerHamper;
double ValueAllHampers;
double ValueItemsLeftOver;
int ItemLeftOver;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of items avalible");
    ValuePerHamper = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of avaliable mac and cheese");
    NumAvalable = sc.nextInt();
    NumHampersMade = NumAvalable/ValuePerHamper;

   // System.out.println("Items left over");
    //NumPerHamper = sc.nextInt();
   // System.out.println("");

    System.out.println(NumHampersMade);


}
```

}

Comment: The naming convention for Java is to always use `camelCase` for variables, and `TitleCase` for class names. I also advise against declaring all of your variables at the top like that, since they make it much harder to see what data types everything has, and make it much easier to make mistakes with which variables have been initialized.

Comment: *"How do you perform arithmetic on values produced by Scanner?"* Same way you perform arithmetic on values from any other source. You write code using the arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`).

Answer (score 1):

cast the divisor to a larger data type eg int a 7, b = 9;
double ave = a / (double)b. either v

Answer (score 0):

That is because integer division will always round down because an int can not have a decimal. Try to use double.

```
double ValuePerHamper, NumAvalable, NumHampersMade;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the number of items avalible");
ValuePerHamper = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the number of avaliable mac and cheese");
NumAvalable = sc.nextDouble();
NumHampersMade = NumAvalable/ValuePerHamper;

System.out.println(NumHampersMade);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error even when I change it to a double and change sc.nextInt(); to a sc.nextDouble();

Comment: @Tyrandis What is the error? By the way, you should be checking for divide by zero.

Comment: Sorry, the error was me not changing NumHampersMade from a int to a double. Thanks! rep+

Comment: Make sure to mark the check if it was the correct answer. Thanks!